# event listeners to form label

Tags: javascript, label, event-listener

So I am trying to make this function use event listeners to the form’s label. Its supposed to takes the element’s id value as its argument, then give each label an id value of id + ‘Label’. It is currently not doing anything when I call it. U and this.$U is other code to shorten the code.

```
    addTooltipHandlers: function(id) {
    'use strict';

    // Get the form element reference:
    var newId = this.$(label.id);

    newId.onmouseover = showTooltip;
    newId.onmouseout = hideTooltip;
    newId.onfocus = showTooltip;
    newId.onblur = hideTooltip;

}, // End of addTooltipHandler() function.
```

I am calling it in another js file using.

```
U.addTooltipHandler('someLabel');
```

Html code I am trying to use it on

```
<div class="two"><label for="phone">Phone Number<span class="tooltip">In the format XXX XXX XXXX or XXX-XXX-XXXX or XXXXXXXXXX.</span></label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required></div>
```

Comment: The second `onmouseover` should probably be `onmouseout`.

Comment: What is `this.$(id)`? Shouldn't that be `document.getElementById(id)`?

Comment: Oh man... cant believe I did that. this.$(id) IS document.getElementByID(id). Its a anonymous function to shorten the code. How do I add the label component to the newId?

Comment: Doesn't my answer show how to do it?

Comment: Hey just saw it, still testing it. The only thing is, I am not sure what I am looking for because there is a enableTooltip that runs and shows that string. When is the addTooltipHandlers supposed look like?

Comment: I don't know, this is your design, I can't see the overall structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
addTooltipHandlers: function(id) {
    'use strict';

    // Define the new ID value:
    var newId = this.$(id + 'label');

    newId.onmouseover = showTooltip;
    newId.onmouseout = hideTooltip;
    newId.onfocus = showTooltip;
    newId.onblur = hideTooltip;

},
```

There's no need to get the element from `id`, you're not doing anything with that element. You just want to concatenate the given ID with `label`, and use that to find the new element to attach the handlers to.

And the second `onmouseover` should be `onmouseout`.

For this to work, you need to give IDs to your labels:

```
<label for="phone" id="phonelabel">
```

Then you can call:

```
U.addToolTipHandlers('phone');
```

Comment: I think I am approaching the label part wrong because id + 'label' would not find anything I think. I am trying var newId = this.$(label.id); the html I am trying to call this on is <div class="two"><label for="phone">Phone Number<span class="tooltip">In the format XXX XXX XXXX or XXX-XXX-XXXX or XXXXXXXXXX.</span></label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required></div>

Comment: Give your label an id, e.g. `<label for="phone" id="phonelabel">`

Comment: Hi Barmer I seem to be running into errors with my hide and show tooltips I get error target.previousSibling.lastChild.style.visibility = 'visible'; I added the code up there

Comment: I'm not really interested in debugging your entire application for you. Learn to use the debugger.